# Where and how is this data being changed?

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

The following code works fine, except that there is some "cleaning up" of the data that is taking place in one instance and not the other that I can't decipher.

I have a table (clientdocs) with a field 'from' that contains string data in the format:

```
Richard Robinson <richard@gmail.com>
```

In my controller, I have code that builds an array for a dropdown from this table:

```
// get clients
$sender_sel = array('Any Sender');

$senders = Clientdoc::orderBy('from', 'ASC')
    ->distinct()
    ->get( array('from') );

foreach($senders as $sender) {
    $sender_sel[] = $sender->from;
}
```

I also retrieve all the data from the table and pass it to the view (along with the above array and other stuff):

```
return View::make('clientdocs/index')
    ->with('date_sel', $date_sel)
    ->with('sender_sel', $sender_sel)
    ->with('docs', Clientdoc::orderBy('date_emailed', 'ASC')->get());
```

Now, in my view:

I use $sender_sel as:

```
{{ Form::select('from', $sender_sel, '', array(
'class' => 'form-control'
)) }}
```

and it displays as expected:

```
"Richard Robinson <richard@gmail.com>"
```

and I also use data from the 2nd query (docs object):

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>From</th>
        <th>Type</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach ($docs as $doc)
        <?php $detail_url = 'clientdocs/' . $doc->id . '/edit' ; ?>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $doc->from }}</td>
        </tr>                       
    @endforeach
</table>
```

Here's the kicker:  $docs->from displays as

```
"Richard Robinson", without the "<richard@gmail.com>"
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View source. It's still there, but `<` and `>` are special characters in HTML (as they're used in HTML tags).

Using triple brackets escapes output in Blade, so `{{{ $doc->from }}}` will fix it by turning it into `&lt;` and `&gt;`.